# Spanned images on Android ListView

Tags: android, html, image, listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to convert an HTML text with images using `Html.fromHtml` and set it inside a ListView, but images appears as squares! I have implemented an imageGetter and also I set

> StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
>   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

to avoid `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Here's my code:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
try {
URL rssUrl = new URL(link);
SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed(); 
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

            return null;
        }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (myRssFeed!=null)
            {

                List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
                for (RSSItem item : myRssFeed.getList()) {
                    Spanned span = Html.fromHtml(item.getDescription().toString(), getImageHTML(), null);           
                    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(0);
                    datum.put("title", item.getTitle());
                    datum.put("desc", span.toString());
                    data.add(datum);

                }
                SimpleAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data, R.layout.listview, new String[] {"title", "desc"}, new int[] {R.id.text1,
                    R.id.text2});


                setListAdapter(adapter2);
```

And here's the ImageGetter:

```
public ImageGetter getImageHTML(){
        ImageGetter ig = new ImageGetter(){
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
             try{
              Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(source).openStream(), "src name");
              d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
              return d;
             }catch(IOException e){
              Log.v("IOException",e.getMessage());
              return null;
             }
            }
           };
       return ig;
   }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ? Can you detail further what have you tried till now ?

Comment: I just updated my post with new info! There's some changes respect my old question because I could implement an ImageGetter but it seems that it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure weather myRssFeed.getList() or item.getDescription() performes any network operation (Just guessing only), Just try adding your for loop logic inside doInBackground method.

```
 List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (RSSItem item : myRssFeed.getList()) {
                Spanned span = Html.fromHtml(item.getDescription().toString(), getImageHTML(), null);           
                Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(0);
                datum.put("title", item.getTitle());
                datum.put("desc", span.toString());
                data.add(datum);

            }
            adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data, R.layout.listview, new String[] {"title", "desc"}, new int[] {R.id.text1,
                R.id.text2});
```

Declare SimpleAdapter adapter2 as a global variable in MyTask and move above code snippet to doInBackground method

Comment: I could implement an ImageGetter and also the text appears fine, but I seems that it doesn't set the images inside the list view. I updated my post with the new information.

Comment: You can't call Drawable.createFromStream method in UI Thread, That is the actual issue I think.

Comment: I think no, because if I use it on a normal textview it works!

Comment: Thank you, but no luck. I think that it's because I want to set the image to a listview and no to a textview.